# After giving height to item div in owl carousel if clicked on dots or arrow navigation doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add the owl carousel to my website. After giving height to item div in owl carousel if click on dots or arrow the slides are not moving. But if I remove the height(class='item') and then if I click on dots or arrow slides are moving.

```
<!---html-->
<section class='about' id='project'>
    <div class='title'>
        <p>Projects</p>
    </div>
    <div class='projects'>
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owls">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 240"><path fill="#D81C4A" fill-opacity="0.2" d="M0,192L360,128L720,192L1080,160L1440,224L1440,320L1080,320L720,320L360,320L0,320Z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</section>

<!---css-->
.projects{
    width:100%;
    height:530px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.owls{
    position: absolute;
    top:38%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    height:240px;
}
.item{
    height:200px;
    margin:20px 40px;
    border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgb(216, 28, 74,0.6);
}
.projects svg{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:1111;
}

<!---jquery-->
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:10,
  nav:true,
  responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      1002:{
        items:1
      }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you explicitly set a `height` for the `div class="item"` elements, you carousel grows until it gets under your `svg` element (which is absoluted positioned with a `z-index` higher than 0).

The upper part of your SVG is transparent, that's why you didn't notice it. Still, it is covering the navigation.

Removing the `z-index` of the `svg` element would be enough to see the navigation working, although I guess you should rework your layout.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I don't know what rework is needed. Any suggestions in layout rework?

Comment: It will depend on what you want to achieve. I imagine the SVG being a footer. If that is the case, you could take it out from the "projects" `div`, place it at the end of the document and have a look to [sticky footers](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/). If the SVG actually belongs to that `div`, you could increment the `div` `height`. Also, you can play with the SVG dimensions ([scaling SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)). In general, try to don't abuse `position=absolute` and make a lot of testing in different screen sizes: SVGs can be tricky.

Comment: If my suggestion had helped you, please, mark my answer as correct. Actually, I will kindly ask you to review all the questions that you have asked in StackOverflow and check if some answers deserve to be also marked as correct. So far you have received 9 answers but have accepted no one :)